# Proof of $(1-e^{ix})^{-1}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, taylor-expansion, proof-explanation

In G.H. Hardy's book 'Divergent Series' there is a claim that $(1-e^{ix})^{-1} = \frac {1}{2} + \frac {1}{2} i \cot (\frac {1} {2} x) $  I, for the life of me, can't get past showing that $(1-e^{ix})^{-1} =$ $$(1+\cos(x)+i\sin(x))/(1-\cos^2(x)-2i\sin(x)\cos(x)-i^2\sin^2(x))$$
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Ugh I can't find the rollback link for my edit, Ross got to all the substantial stuff before I did, so I think my edit just made it worse.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend starting from the RHS, and converting trig functions to exponentials:

$$\begin{align}
{1\over2}+{1\over2}i\cot\left({1\over2}x\right)&={1\over2}\left(1+i{\cos(x/2)\over\sin(x/2)} \right)\\
&={1\over2}\left({\sin(x/2)+i\cos(x/2)\over\sin(x/2)} \right)\\
&={1\over2}\left({e^{ix/2}-e^{-ix/2}\over2i}+i{e^{ix/2}+e^{-ix/2}\over2}\over{e^{ix/2}-e^{-ix/2}\over2i} \right)\\
&={1\over2}\left({e^{ix/2}-e^{-ix/2}\over2i}-{e^{ix/2}+e^{-ix/2}\over2i}\over{e^{ix/2}-e^{-ix/2}\over2i} \right)\quad\text{(look closely for what changed here!)}\\
&={1\over2}\left(-2e^{-ix/2}\over{e^{ix/2}-e^{-ix/2}}\right)\\
&={1\over1-e^{ix}}
\end{align}$$

Note:  This could probably be more cleanly done by making the second line read

$$={1\over2}\left({2i\sin(x/2)-2\cos(x/2)\over2i\sin(x/2)} \right)$$

so that you can go straight to

$$={1\over2}\left({(e^{ix/2}-e^{-ix/2})-(e^{ix/2}+e^{-ix/2})\over e^{ix/2}-e^{-ix/2}} \right)$$

etc.

Comment: Is there any way to do it from the LHS?

Comment: @Ethan, just write the string of equations backwards!

Comment: Why did you take the i out and make that part of the expression negative?

Comment: @Ethan, I'm not sure which expression you're referring to.  Do you mean the one in my note about doing things more cleanly?  If so, the idea there was to get rid all the messy fractions within fractions by multiplying numerator and denominator by $2i$ and note that $2i\cdot i=-2$.

Comment: The expression immediately above 'look closely at what changed here'

Comment: Oh, all I did there was move the $i$ into the denominator, so that all the little denominators would be of the same form, $2i$.  The expression became negative because $i=-1/i$.

Comment: Ah, okay.  I wasn't aware that 1/i is the same as -i.   Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2):

Let $y=\cos(x) + i\sin(x)$. This factors into $\frac{1+y}{1-y^2}=\frac{1}{1-y}=(1-y)^{-1}$, implying $e^{ix}=\cos(x)+i\sin(x)$.